# c++ Accessing members of objects using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have variable `mode`, which I am declaring with the following line:

```
StatusRecord mode;
```

`StatusRecord` is a `struct` which holds several variables of different types.

I now want to create a pointer to `mode`, and populate that pointer with some data by using a function to populate its attributes/ fields. I have tried doing this as follows:

```
StatusRecord mode;
StatusRecord *modePtr = &mode;
DataStore->getModeData(*modePtr);
```

Here, I am declaring the `struct` variable, creating a pointer to it, and populating that pointer using the `getModeData()` function. However, I now want to use an attribute of the `struct ptr` I've just populated in a conditional statement:

```
if(*modePtr->eraseSelect ==2){
    ...
}
```

But I'm getting a compile error on this line that says:

> Error: operand of '*' must be a pointer

Does this mean that the `eraseSelect` attribute should be a pointer as well as 'modePtr`? How would I fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need to dereference your pointer here:

```
if(modePtr->eraseSelect ==2){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
if(modePtr->eraseSelect ==2){
    ...
}
```

or this:

```
if((*modePtr).eraseSelect ==2){
    ...
}
```

So you can use "dot" syntax to reach fields of an instance or "arrow" syntax to reach fields of a pointer to the instance. In most cases, "arrow" is more suitable.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is at `*modePtr->eraseSelect`.

The `->` is used to access member variables of pointers to objects. So, `ptr->someMember` is equivalent to `*(ptr).someMember`. You are mixing up the two, and so it doesn't make sense as you are dereferencing twice.

You should instead use `modePtr->eraseSelect` instead.